Does Taiwan use a payment system like WeChat?
As I understand it, smartphone electronic payment (WeChat) is the de facto and sometimes required payment modality in mainland China now in 2024.
Is there a situation similar in Taipei?  Or is it more like the US (cash, Apple Pay and credit cards).

From a recent trip to mainland China, while it is true that WeChat is the standard method of payment virtually everywhere, every single human vendor I encountered would also take cash. Vending machines might be electronic payment only.

Cash is the de facto standard of payment in Taiwan. There are many vendors, shops, restaurants and stalls that only accept cash. Local transportation also tends to be paid cash.
Larger establishments such as hotels, trains and rentals accept credit cards. Although I had no trouble using a VISA or MasterCard credit cards in places like that, smaller shops that did accept cards often did not work with either. A card network called Union Pay is more commonly accepted.
This situation extends to ATM. Except in Taipei, it was very difficult to find an ATM to withdraw cash from. It took many tries and research to identify ATMs that would allow me to withdraw cash, even when they were in fact by the same apparent bank as my debit card. Be sure to take out enough cash when you are in Taipei until you can reach another major city.

UnionPay works with Discover/DinersClub cards from outside Asia.

Although I've seen those logos too, I do not recall ever seeing one of those cards! They are certainly not common in the Americas.

Discover is very popular in the US. DinersClub cards are usually co-branded with something else (Visa/MC/Discover), rarely do I see DinersClub branded cards on their own nowadays.

@Itai UnionPay is a (the?) Chinese system for cards.

Is your experience recent? While I have never visited Taiwan, I’m surprised such an economy is still cash-based, especially after the pandemic.

Yes, exactly a year ago, and Japan is still similar too. Despite the modernity of everything else in those countries, cash is still the main form of payment, Taiwan more so, particularly for street food which in some small towns is the majority of meal options.

Japan is not really cash based any longer. I got scared into taking out cash in Japan by one too many travel sites and ended up buying random Pokemon souvenirs at the airport just to get rid if it. I think I encountered one place in 2 weeks that didn't take cards.

Recent? I was there just last August and we did see a lot of cash in use regularly, particularly for food and souvenir stalls, entrances and such.

@Itai the important question is this: even though the majority of locals in Taiwan and Japan still pay in cash, is it possible to pay by card? If it's possible, I don't care if the locals do it or not.

@Johnnyjanko Not for everything. You would miss a lot of what Taiwan has to offer. On the other hand, if you were there just for business and only went to higher-end restaurants, take transport that does accept cards, it may be possible not to take out any cash.
